# Validate PowerShell variable contents - alphanumeric, dot, dash and length limitation

Tags: powershell

Can anyone recommend a short and efficient way of validating the contents of the variable $name, so that it will conform with the following:

- Only English alphanumeric characters
- Dots "." are allowed
- Dashes "-" are allowed
- Length should not exceed 10 characters

I can think of long, cumbersome ways of doing that, but I would much rather use an elegant implementation. Something like preg_match in php.

I'll be running it with PowerShell on Windows 2012 Server.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask].

Comment: Having said that, I'll suggest that regular expressions, which are supported in PowerShell, may be helpful.

Comment: `^[a-z0-9.-]{1,10}$`.

Comment: `If ($name -match '(\w|\.|-){1,10}') { }`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Escaping the dot isn't required in a character class.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Good to know.  Thank you.  It gets hard to keep track of what does and does not need escaping or is or is not regex in PS!  As a note to the OP, if your `$name` variable is a function/script parameter, you can utilize `[ValidateScript({})]`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 or [ValidatePattern()] if you're using Regex and you don't mind yucky messages

Comment: @MikeShepard Forgot that one exists.  I typically use script so I can throw my own messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$string="tEst-.gg"


If ($string -match '^[a-z0-9.-]{1,10}$') 
{ 
    "OK"
}
```

If you want autorise empty string, replace {1,10} by {0,10}

Comment: The `A-Z` is redundant, since the `-match` operator is case-insensitive.